# how can i retrieve the string which is present "" from javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

My requirement I have the hi "Hello" world string then i need to retrieve the substring as "hello"(which is present in quotes).this string is present in java script.

How can I retrieve the substring which is present in quotes?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Helps to give a code snippet instead of trying to explain your string in words. And JavaScript is one word, not two.

Comment: How did you determine that you wanted “hello”? Because it’s the first English word? All the text before a space? The first five letters (if so, use [`theString.substring(0,4)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring))?

Comment: _All the text before the first space? All the text before the last space?_ All but the last six characters? Everything up to and including the first "o"? The first half of the string, rounding down? _Will anything that maps from "Hello world" to "hello" do?_

Comment: Please provide a real world example.

Comment: Please don't change your question entirely by edits. Better, ask a new question. Better yet, ask a question where the requirements are stated, not merely a single test case. Even better, do your research ("regex tutorial", "javascript regex", ignore w3schools results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this  `/("(\\"|[^"])+")/g`

[**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnvPy/)

Comment: +1, but probably better to use `[^"]` so it's more explicit.

Comment: @Pavne did you solved the problem now

Comment: don't forget `toLower` the string. He wants "hello" from "Hello world" (but he also says "substring", so I'm confused)

Comment: sorry i will update it

Comment: He changed the questioh now.When i gave answer he asked in another way

Comment: I suggest you run away from this question now, and never show up.

Comment: I rolled back to the previous question. Let's see how long it stays that way.

Comment: @PSR if string is static then i get the substring using your solution.But I need to retrieve the substring which is dynamically appear.

Comment: Then you can direclty apply  dynamicstring.match(r);